# How can I access my microcontroller's clock frequency and make it work at 16 MHz?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, baudrate

I wrote a USART communication code in bare metal mode (On STM32F107). And what I wrote in the "Baud rate" section( to select the baud rate):

`USART2 -> BRR = 0x0683; //Baud rate of 9600 @16MHz`

This 9600 is written based on clock freq. of 16 MHz but my XTAL is greyed and undefined !! and I don't know what is the frequency actually!

That is my question and also wanted to know how can I make XTAL work again! At first when I installed Keil, it was working properly but after sometime went greyed out.

Comment: Look at the datasheet and find out what internal clock sources there are and how you selected one. Or look at the hardware and see what external clock sources there are and how you selected one. There's also PLLs to multiply the clock if necessary. We can't possibly know your hardware and code to know what clock you have.

Comment: Same thing as with USART, you only need to right to specific registers dururing startup to setup all PLLs and dividers and stuff. I suggest you try generating code for your MCU in STM32CubeIDE (specifically CubeMX code generator) and just take the code from there. You don't even have to upload the code, just make it generate the code for you and copy-paste it (and edit if necessary)

Comment: What frequently crystal is wired up to your STM32...? If you didn't design the circuit board, then look at the information from the person who did.

Comment: If you don't know, you should read the data sheet and application notes. Freely downloadable stuffs.

Comment: These devices start up using the internal RC oscillator and *you have to specifically switch oscillator sources* in your code (or implement it in the HAL / Cube)..

Comment: YO Thanks people!!

Comment: Hm, I saw this very same question some time ago, and "answered" by similar comments...

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks sir